# Need help on /kill command an usage of @e

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi everybody I need some help with minecraft.
I an a command : `/kill @e[type=!Player,ArmorStand]` and it didn't work
What I wanted : A command that kills every entity except ArmorStand and Players. Could someone help me?

Comment: It is... the solution there will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Target selectors cannot accept multiple arguments of the same type.

To get around this, you should first create a dummy scoreboard objective like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Kill dummy
```

Then, in this order, run the following commands:

```
/scoreboard players set @e Kill 1
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] Kill 0
/scoreboard players set @a Kill 0
```

Now every entity that you want to kill should have a Kill score of 1, and Players/ArmorStands a kill score of 0.

All you have to do next is kill all entities with a kill score of at least 1:

```
/kill @e[score_Kill_min=1]
```